# Select all occurrences of select word not quite working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had to reset my VS Code settings back to defaults and I'm finding the ability to select text and find all occurrences of that text is not quite working as it used to. In the screenshot below, after selecting `BaseTemplate` inside `IBaseTemplateProps` on line 3 and then pressing CTRL+D multiple times to add to the multi-cursor selection, it cannot seem to include BaseTemplate in IBaseTemplateProps on line 6.

This is different behaviour prior to resetting VS Code settings back to defaults where it would pick up all occurrences even if the selected text was a partial match of longer words. Can anyone confirm this is expected behaviour and if not, what non-default setting do I need to change to get that behaviour back?

[image: VS Code multi-cursor select]

Comment: looks like `Ctrl+D` is searching with word boundaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected for me.  You probably have the `Match Whole Word` option enabled in the Find Widget.  VS Code will use that option if enabled even if the Find Widget is not visible.

When the Find Widget is not visible, its options will show briefly in the upper right corner of the editor when you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.  You can click the `Match Whiole Word` option to disable it and see if it works as you expect thereafter.